# My function is returning this, error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl MEAN

Tags: lnk2019

```
double mean(int A[], int size)
{
int count = size;
    double sum = std::accumulate(A, A + count, 0 );
double ave = sum / count;
    return ave;
}
```

I've included numeric but dont know what to do from here

Comment: Did you spell your function `mean` in one place but `MEAN` in another?

Comment: @nneonneo won't it rise some kind of `undefined symbol` error as `c++` is case-sensetive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)